# how can i edit event's data like location and venue using graph api or fql for IOS Application?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios4, facebook-fql

I am searching this solution since last two weeks and still stuck on that, i tried FQL to get solution but i think FQL not support UPDATE query, and searched also graph api but can't get any healthy response that how can i get solution, Please please if some one know how can i edit events information help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need `create_event` permissions to modify an event.

To modify an existing event, HTTP `post` to the Graph API `https://graph.facebook.com/{event_id}?access_token={access token}` with the appropriate parameters specified in the formpost. Location is `location` and venue is `venue` with fields: street, city, state, zip, country, latitude, and longitude.